# Does Yandex eventually start asking for phone numbers for verification?

Tags: yandex-mail

I have multiple Yandex email accounts and haven't experienced any issues like asking phone numbers for verification. But I read somewhere on the web that some people are being asked for phone number verification though they signed as "I don't have a phone number."

Answer (score 4):

A few days ago, while trying to log in, Yandex told me that my account had been likely hacked and asked me to change my password, a thing I could not do without a phone number.

After gaining again access to my account I could not detect any suspicious activity there. The only mistake I could have made might have been a one time error while writing the password. So a wrong password.

Anyway, if you do not provide them with a valid phone number and do not get the verification code from them by SMS there is no way you can recover your account.

It looks like this is a trick. Yandex does not ask for a phone number while signing up for an account but later, under the pretext of a security threat, they block your account and you are obliged to send them a phone number.

Comment: I can confirm that a one time misspelling of your password is a possible cause.  But unfortunately I was able to recover my account by only knowing the exact date I registered, and possibly because I got the password right after a while and from the same IP.

Comment: They did it to me too. I only used them for their cloud drive. Their support agent asked me to send in my identification documents if I did not want to use my phone number… So I withdrew most of my sensitive documents (which were encrypted) and refrained from uploading anything security-related.

Comment: Register without a mobile number, explore around your new account, personalize, add backup email.  Maybe around ten clicks or 10 minutes, you will be forced to enter a mobile number where they will send you a confirmation code.

I suspect this is to remain in the top lists of free email providers which do not require mobile numbers.  Those list creators were able to register and login once without a mobile number.  They do not try to actually use it for any length of time.

Answer (score 2):

It must be a security measure if so, however I have had a Yandex Mail account since 2014 and I have never been asked for phone number verification. And I have;

- Logged in from different parts of the world
- Logged in with VPNs
- Logged in with various devices
- Usually logged in with cookies cleared
- Logged in after repeated failed password attempts

I never have, and never intend to use their phone verification feature.

[image: Yandex Mail Account]

Comment: Same here, I have been using it since '15. I have never been asked for phone verification but I found on the internet somewhere that users have been asked to verify for at least once.