# Is it true that Yandex started blocking accounts to which a phone number is not attached?

Tags: yandex-mail

I am asking very different question from [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113480/does-yandex-eventually-start-asking-for-phone-numbers-for-verification/113542).

[Here](https://sudonull.com/post/12784-Yandex-blocks-accounts-to-which-a-phone-number-is-not-attached) is the user wrote scary article about

> Yandex blocks accounts to which a phone number is not attached.

Is it true that Yandex started blocking accounts to which a phone number is not attached?